# CreateFile(ComX...) error C2664: 'CreateFileW':

Tags: c, winapi

I have to transmit information from a uController to my Laptop. When I create the file I get the following error. I think it is easier to troubleshoot if you see the script.

Because it says that 'char [20]' in 'LPCWSTR' doesnt fit, I changed it like this:

```
CreateFile((LPCWSTR)name, GENERIC..
```

Now I can compile the program, but I still get INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, and I'm not able to open the Port.

My Serial routine:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "com_bg.hpp"

char name[20]="";       //between the "" inserting COM"X"

...

do
{
    port = CreateFile(name, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    if (port==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        k++;
    } 

}
while ((k<MAXCREAT) && (port==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE));

if (k==MAXCREAT)
    return(ERR_COM);

...
```

My main Looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "com_bg.hpp"
#include "com._bg.cpp"
#include "tchar.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR *argv[])
{   
     printf("Hello\n");

     getch();

     err = openCom(8, 9600, NONE,1,RTSDTRLOW);

     if (err != OK)
     {
         closeCom();

         printf("Failed to OpenPort\n");

         return 0;
     }
    …
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type-casting will not change the underlying encoding of strings.  If you need to call `CreateFile` for a file or device name that is represented in a `char *` string, use `CreateFileA`, either explicitly or by changing your project settings to not use Unicode.

That is, of course, if you really want to pass a `char *` string to `CreateFile`. The more sensible option is to change the type of `name` from `char` to `wchar_t` (the Windows 
platform type being `WCHAR`).

Comment: Becouse the COM Port is always Changing im typing in the char manually trough console. So i have to use the char. When I Change to "wchar_t" or "WCHAR" it say:     *C2440: 'Initialisierung': 'const char [1]' cant  'wchar_t [20]'*

Comment: @Sebastian Initialize wide strings with the L-prefix: `L"Hello World";`